# Wildfly 15 and Jersey - Trying to register multiple service locators into single service locator application

Tags: jakarta-ee, jersey, wildfly, jersey-2.0, hk2

We are investigating moving an application currently working on Weblogic to `Wildfly 15.0.1.Final`.

Our project is an ear which contains multiple wars, two of which are making use of Jersey (2.27) for restful webservices. These are an 'api' war and a 'web' war, the endpoints of which are accessible at "host_name/application/api/" and "host_name/application/web/" respectively.

We are currently adding our jersey libraries into a lib folder in the ear using the 'earlib' gradle statement while our wars use 'providedCompile'. In an effort to allow us to continue using this setup, we have removed jax-rs from our standalone.xml.

If I remove one of these wars from the deployment, it deploys fine and the webservices work as expected. However, if I try to deploy both, we receive an error telling us it is `Trying to register multiple service locators into single service locator application`. The full stacktrace is included below, and I have included our web.xml files for the two wars in question.

Any suggestions on how to get past this issue? I'd be happy to provide any other code snippets or information that may be of use.

Cheers

**Stacktrace:**

```
17:14:15,716 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."application-core.ear"."application-api.war".undertow-deployment: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."application-core.ear"."application-api.war".undertow-deployment: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: Trying to register multiple service locators into single service locator application.  
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)  
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)  
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266)  
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)  
at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)  
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)  
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)  
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)  
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)  
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)  
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: Trying to register multiple service locators into single service locator application.  
at org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.SingleInjectionManagerStore.registerInjectionManager(SingleInjectionManagerStore.java:64)  
at org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider.addInjectionManager(CdiComponentProvider.java:778)  
at org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider.initialize(CdiComponentProvider.java:197)  
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ComponentProviderConfigurator.lambda$null$0(ComponentProviderConfigurator.java:79)  
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$11$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:372)  
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)  
at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382)  
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)  
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)  
at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)  
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)  
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)  
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ComponentProviderConfigurator.lambda$init$1(ComponentProviderConfigurator.java:80)  
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Values$LazyValueImpl.get(Values.java:341)  
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationConfigurator.createApplication(ApplicationConfigurator.java:122)  
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationConfigurator.init(ApplicationConfigurator.java:96)  
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.lambda$initialize$0(ApplicationHandler.java:313)  
at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.forEach(Arrays.java:3880)  
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:313)  
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:282)  
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:335)  
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:178)  
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:370)  
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)  
at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)  
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)  
at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)  
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:303)  
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:143)  
at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:583)  
at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:554)  
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)  
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)  
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)  
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)  
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)  
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)  
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)  
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)  
at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:596)  
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:97)  
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)  
... 9 more  


17:14:18,429 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "application-core.ear")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"application-core.ear\".\"application-api.war\".undertow-deployment" => "javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: Trying to register multiple service locators into single service locator application.  
    Caused by: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: Trying to register multiple service locators into single service locator application."}}  
17:14:18,429 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "application-core.ear" was rolled back with the following failure message:   
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"application-core.ear\".\"application-api.war\".undertow-deployment" => "javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: Trying to register multiple service locators into single service locator application.  
    Caused by: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: Trying to register multiple service locators into single service locator application."}}  
[2019-03-20 05:14:18,850] Artifact application-core.ear: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.  
[2019-03-20 05:14:18,850] Artifact application-core.ear: java.lang.Exception: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"application-core.ear\".\"application-api.war\".undertow-deployment" => "javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: Trying to register multiple service locators into single service locator application.  
    Caused by: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: Trying to register multiple service locators into single service locator application."}}
```

**API web.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">


  <display-name>Application REST API</display-name>


  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  ...
  <servlet>
    <display-name>REST API</display-name>
    <servlet-name>ApplicationApiApp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
      <param-value>com.test.application.core.apiservice.api.app.ApplicationApiApp</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <!-- Register resources and providers under  "infrastructure" package. -->
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>
        io.swagger.v3.jaxrs2.integration.resources, com.test.application.core.apiservice.api.infrastructure
      </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>openApi.configuration.prettyPrint</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
      <param-value>
      org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature;org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature
      </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.monitoring.statistics.enabled</param-name>
      <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ApplicationApiApp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**WEB web.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">


  <display-name>Application WEB</display-name>


  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  ...

  <servlet>
    <display-name>Application Web App</display-name>
    <servlet-name>ApplicationWebApp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
      <param-value>com.test.application.web.app.ApplicationWebApp</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <!-- Register resources and providers under  "infrastructure" package. -->
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>
        io.swagger.v3.jaxrs2.integration.resources, com.test.application.web
      </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>openApi.configuration.prettyPrint</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
      <param-value>
      org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature;org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature
      </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.monitoring.statistics.enabled</param-name>
      <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ApplicationWebApp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Why are you using a 3rd party JAX-RS solution when both WebLogic and Wildfly already have an implementation?  Jersey isn't needed outside of a Tomcat type of environment.

Answer (score 1):

By default Jersey is using a `*Single*InjectionManagerStore`:

```
/**
 * Default {@link InjectionManagerStore injection manager} that assumes only one
 * {@link InjectionManager injection manager} per application is used.
 */
```

You can switch to an alternate impl by creating a flat file "org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.spi.InjectionManagerStore" placed under META-INF/services. This file has to contain a single line with the classname of the choosen impl. You could maybe try to use the `'ServletInjectionManagerStore'` one.

See full example [here](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/ext/cdi/jersey-cdi1x-servlet/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.ExternalRequestScope).

Notice also the comments: "*Enabled multiple Jersey apps within a single WAR/JVM*" :-)

Good luck

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks. I was actually not including the `jersey-cdi1x-servlet` library that contains the `ServletInjectionManagerStore` you mentioned, but once added this looked promising. However, after some further discussion we decided that we would remove the requirement for cdi from both of these wars, bypassing the problem altogether.